# How to scrape item with same class name in Reddit that uses Javascript or Json?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, scrape

I am getting a hardtime scrape the URL item in Reddit

I used `response.xpath` but I don't know why it's just getting two items only. I also use `crawlera` for IP ban. But my real concern is how to get the items.

Here's the URL:

https://www.reddit.com/r/teslamotors/new/

My code:

```
response.xpath("//a[@class = 'b5szba-0 fMXvWW']/@href").getall()
```

Output:

```
['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xWPM9HkwLn4&feature=youtu.be', 'https://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/british-columbia/man-nearly-run-over-by-suv-as-boat-and-suv-sink-1.5139313']
```

Desired Output is to get the "HREF" text of these sample URL (Red with elipsis)

```
fox40.com/2019/0...
i.imgur.com/OYWPxF...
youtu.be/jQioNt...
etc
```

Any idea please?

Comment: Mabye you can try using `data-click-id="body"`?

Comment: Hi @antfuentes87 sorry what do you mean?